# Bull-arena show bull queues

Tags: node.js, redis, queue

I've configured my bull and created a queue.

```
import * as Queue from 'bull';

var emailQueue = new Queue('emails', {redis: {port: 6379, host: '127.0.0.1'}});

emailQueue.process(function(job, done){
    done();
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    emailQueue.add({from: 'someone@email.com'}, {removeOnComplete:true});
  }, 5000);
```

and I've configured my arena like this:

```
const Arena = require('bull-arena');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const arenaConfig = Arena({
  queues: [
    {
        name: "emails",
        hostId: "MyAwesomeQueues",
        redis: {
            port: 6379,
            host: "localhost"
        },
    },
  ],
},
{
  basePath: '/arena',
  disableListen: true
});

app.use('/', arenaConfig);
const PORT = 1231;
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("running on port ", PORT)
})
```

bull-arena shows my queue, but waiting, active, completed, failed, delayed, and paused are still showing 0.

and I have one more question: Is there a way that I can configure arena without mentioning name of my queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason the host for Queue and Arena configurations are not the same?  Currently one uses '127.0.0.1' and the other 'localhost'.

Use the redis-cli to check to see if bull is adding the jobs to the queue.

You should see bull entries in redis similar to this image
[image: You should see bull entries in redis similar to this image.]

As for the name of the queue, that has to match so Arena can display the correct queue's jobs.